# I need to know a javascript code

Tags: javascript

this code does something when i press the spacebar. i would like to change the spacebar to the mouse button.please help

```
$("#cvs").keydown(function(c){32==c.which&&shootBullet(player)});
```

Comment: `.click` would seem appropriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#cvs").click(function() {
  shootBullet(player);
 });
```

This changes the event type to "click", and removes the `c.which === 32` because that is only applicable to key events (the `if` condition originally checked if the key being pressed was "Space", so that way pressing another key wouldn't shoot a bullet. But since you want to use Mouse events, this is not applicable).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change keydown do click.

Comment: Also need to remove `32 == c.which`